# How to automatically indent a list with {cli}?

Tags: r

I want to create two lists of files with {cli}. Oddly enough, I didn't find a simple way to do it. For now, this is what I have:

```r
library(cli)

f <- function() {
  cli::cli_div(theme = list(ul = list(`margin-left` = 2, before = "")))
  
  cli::cli_text("this is my first list:")
  cli::cli_ul()
  for (i in c("a", "b", "c")) {
    cli::cli_li("{.file {i}}")
  }
  
  cli::cli_text("this is my second list:")
  cli::cli_ul()
  for (i in c("d", "e", "f")) {
    cli::cli_li("{.file {i}}")
  }
  
  cli::cli_alert_info("this is an info")
}

f()
#> this is my first list:
#>   • 'a'
#>   • 'b'
#>   • 'c'
#>   this is my second list:
#>       • 'd'
#>       • 'e'
#>       • 'f'
#>       ℹ this is an info
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As you can see, there is a formatting problem. This is the expected output:

```r
#> this is my first list:
#>   • 'a'
#>   • 'b'
#>   • 'c'
#> this is my second list:
#>   • 'd'
#>   • 'e'
#>   • 'f'
#> ℹ this is an info
```

Do you know a way to have this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to give an id to each `cli_ul` and to use this id to close them with `cli_end`:

```r
library(cli)

f <- function() {

  cli::cli_div(theme = list(ul = list(`margin-left` = 2, before = "")))
  cli::cli_text("this is my first list:")
  cli::cli_ul(id = "foo")
  for (i in c("a", "b", "c")) {
    cli::cli_li("{.file {i}}")
  }
  cli::cli_end(id = "foo")
  
  cli::cli_text("this is my first list:")
  cli::cli_ul(id = "foo2")
  for (i in c("a", "b", "c")) {
    cli::cli_li("{.file {i}}")
  }
  cli::cli_end(id = "foo2")
  
  cli::cli_alert_info("this is an info")
}

f()
#> this is my first list:
#>   • 'a'
#>   • 'b'
#>   • 'c'
#> this is my first list:
#>   • 'a'
#>   • 'b'
#>   • 'c'
#> ℹ this is an info
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>